# Excel custom formula with IF statements and INDEX, MATCH returns a #VALUE error

Tags: vba, excel, function, custom-function

I am extracting values from one Excel sheet to another. I use the following formula:

```
= IF(ISBLANK(IFNA(INDEX(Range1;Row;MATCH(Dates;Range2;0));Error1));Error2;IFNA(INDEX(Range1;Row;MATCH(Dates;Range2;0));Error1))
```

Since I need to do calculations with the extracted data I wanted to create a custom function which would simplify the extraction process by eliminating the need to type the parameters which stay the same every time. So I built the following function:

```
Function DataCap(Dates As Variant, Row As Variant) As Variant

   Dim Range1 As Range 'Define the whole lookup table
       Set Range1 = Range("Data!A1:P151")

   Dim Range2 As Range 'Define the date lookup table
       Set Range2 = Range("Data!A3:P3")

   Dim Error1 As Range 'Define the error 1; if no value
       Set Error1 = Range("X16")

   Dim Error2 As Range 'Define the error 2; if blank
       Set Error2 = Range("Y16")

   DataCap.Formula "= IF(ISBLANK(IFNA(INDEX(Range1;Row;MATCH(Dates;Range2;0));Error1));Error2;IFNA(INDEX(Range1;Row;MATCH(Dates;Range2;0));Error1))"


End Function
```

When I run it I get the #VALUE error. If I paste the equation (with the same arguments) directly in the cell, it works as expected. So, I think the problem is that VBA not able to do the calculation. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Thank you for the help in advance

Comment: Have you defined `Range`, `Range2`, `Error1` and `Error2` as named ranges?

Comment: You can't use VBA variable names in a formula, and you need to use commas not semicolons in the formula string.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie, no the Range, Range2 etc. are defined only in the code, not in the Excel Sheet.

Comment: @Rory thanks for the input, my local Excel version requires semicolons rather than commas. If I cannot use variable names in the formula, is there an alternative?

Comment: It doesn't matter - the `Formula` property requires you to use US settings in the code. I also don't follow what you are trying to do - a function does not have a `Formula` property, so what do you hope to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being able to test it on your data I can't be sure if this would work, but it might at least be able to point you more in the right direction.

```
Public Function DCap(xDates As Variant, xRow As Variant)
Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range, Error1 As Range, Error2 As Range

Set Range1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A1:P151")
Set Range2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A3:P3")

Set Error1 = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("X16")
Set Error2 = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("Y16")

On Error Resume Next
If IsError(WorksheetFunction.Index(Range1, xRow, WorksheetFunction.Match(xDates, Range2, 0))) Then
    DCap = Error1
ElseIf Len(WorksheetFunction.Index(Range1, xRow, WorksheetFunction.Match(xDates, Range2, 0))) = 0 Then
    DCap = Error2
Else
    DCap = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range1, xRow, WorksheetFunction.Match(xDates, Range2, 0))
End If
On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you very much.

Comment: could you also please explain what was it that caused problems in my original script, so I know for next time?

Comment: VBA functions will always return a value, rather than a formula (since in essence the function IS the formula), so trying to build around that model is primarily what I did differently. I just split your formula into its base parts and re-wrote it in VBA, using WorksheetFunction where applicable to keep its operation as similar to how it was originally written. The first `If` checks to see the `Index` is an error, and if so, returns Error1; the second `If` checks to see if the `Index` is blank (i.e. length = 0), and if so, returns Error2; if neither of these are true, it returns the `Index`.

Comment: Also, you have to set ranges a little differently in VBA than in formulas, specifically referencing the sheet name using the `Sheets("sheet_name").Range("A1:B1")` syntax, rather than `Range("sheet_name!A1:B1")`. If you haven't tried it out, using the Macro Recorder (Developer Tab, Record Macro) to do stuff can be a big help in just figuring out the syntax for how stuff is referenced.